# Unable to create Wiki page using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to edit a page on a Wiki that uses MediaWiki software, but it is not working. I am able to succesfully log in, but unable to edit pages. I am unsure what is causing this problem, as I included the edit token in my request. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


def get_login_token(raw_resp):
    soup = bs(raw_resp.text, 'lxml')
    token = [n.get('value', '') for n in soup.find_all('input')
             if n.get('name', '') == 'wpLoginToken']
    return token[0]

def get_edit_token(raw_resp):
    soup = bs(raw_resp.text, 'lxml')
    token = [n.get('value', '') for n in soup.find_all('input')
             if n.get('name', '') == 'wpEditToken']
    return token[0]

#login
s = requests.Session()
values = {'wpName' : 'username',
        'wpPassword' : 'password',
         'wpLoginAttempt' : 'Log in',
         'wpForceHttps' : '1',
         'wpLoginToken' : ''
          }

url = '.....'
resp = s.get(url)
values['wpLoginToken'] = get_login_token(resp)
req = s.post(url, values)


# edit page
url1 = '.....'
editing = {'wpTextbox1' : 'hi there',
           'wpSave' : 'Save page',
           'wpSummary' : 'hi',
           'wpEditToken' : ''}
resp = s.get(url1)
editing['wpEditToken'] = get_edit_token(resp)

edit = s.post(url1, editing)

print(edit.url)
print(edit.content)
```

Comment: You are assigning `req = s.post(url, values)`. That's a *response* however - probably the one you're trying to read the edit token from later with `get_edit_token(resp)` - but  `resp` at that point is still the first response (the response to the login request).

Comment: What do you mean? I get the edit token from reading in resp where it is defined as 'resp = s.get(url1)'

Comment: Ah, you're right, I missed that request in between the other two. Never mind then.

Comment: So what's the result? Status code of the last response? Is it a redirect ([check `edit.history`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) if necessary)? What does the response content look like?

Comment: Also: Have you considered using the [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page/en)?

Comment: Are you referring to edit.content? It is basically a bunch of gibberish, but it the edit is not getting saved, and the program is not navigating away from the edit page either, which means something is wrong.

Comment: Yes. Save it to a `.html` file and open it locally in a browser. There may be an "You're not authorized..." message or something else in that gibberish that might give you an indication to what you're missing. Chances are, there's some additional hidden fields you need to send, like a CSRF token.

Comment: Hmm, I read over the source code for other parameters and tokens (they all start with wp) and there don't appear to be any more, besides the ones I included.